# DB2 database special characters for insert into table

Tags: java, database, db2

Where can i find the list of all special characters which need to be escaped before insertion in table like following:

```
& -> &amp;
< -> &lt; 
> -> &gt;
```

I am using db2 database and java application for inserting into table.

Thanks,
Suraj

Comment: These look like HTML escape characters.  Here is a list http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php?PHPSESSID=8cbbddde9a9c9825467546f1c98fe119.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no "special characters" in SQL databases (including DB2), unless they are special to the application doing the inserting. If you are using parameterized statements: `INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES (?)`, anything goes. If you are using string literals: `INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES ('mystring')`, you only need to escape single quotation marks by doubling them: `INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES ('I''m quoting a "''"')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to escape XML/HTML entities, you can use the `XMLTEXT` function as follows:

```
SELECT XMLTEXT('<This & that>') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

```
&lt;This &amp; that&gt;
```